# $("#Test") becomes Object instead of jQuery in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have javascript that works on most browsers except for Safari in Ipad, Iphone, or Safari for Windows.

LobbyMenuGames becomes an jQuery object on desktop browsers IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I get this message.

[1 http://www.nurgi.com/atsso/working.png](http://www.nurgi.com/atsso/working.png)

But if I try to open in Safari I get this message.

[1 http://www.nurgi.com/atsso/safari.png](http://www.nurgi.com/atsso/safari.png)

The problem seams like Safari fires $(document).ready(function () prematurely but I'm not sure. I can get the variable to be jQuery object if I declare it again in a onclick event.

You can duplicate the same error by going to http://nurgi.com/atsso/test.aspx on your iphone.

This is a simplified code with the extra codes removed:

```
var LobbyMenuGames;  // Global Variable


$(document).ready(function ()
{
    if (LobbyMenuGames == null)
        LobbyMenuGames = $("#LobbyMenuGames"); // <-- This becomes an Object instead of jQuery object

    TestIsObj("OnReady After");

});


function TestIsObj(loc)
{
    var nl = "\n";
    var s = loc + nl;

    if (LobbyMenuGames instanceof jQuery)
        s = s + " IS jQuery" + nl;
    else
        s = s + " NOT jQuery" + nl;
    if (LobbyMenuGames instanceof Object)
        s = s + " IS Object" + nl;
    else
        s = s + " NOT Object" + nl;

    alert(s);
}
```

Comment: ...if `LobbyMenuGames` was `null` or `undefined`, the `instanceof` operator would give you `false`.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. In your `TestIsObj()` function, try adding `s = s + LobbyMenuGames.jquery` to see what it gives you. You should get a version number.

Comment: using fn.jquery returns "Unable to get property 'jquery' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: `LobbyMenuGames.jquery` My first comment was mistaken with the `.fn`, which is why I deleted and reposted it. I'm curious. Is this question just about the `alert()` output, or was there an actual issue in your code. I looked at the solution you used, and if there was a `.ready()` issue, that wouldn't fix it, though it would be useful to conceal an error.

Comment: ...ultimately your issue seems to be that you're running your test from within the `.ready()` callback, but you have some other code that's trying to use the code that relies on `LobbyMenuGames`. This may result in other issues. Make sure all code that relies on the DOM being ready doesn't run too soon.

Comment: ...There must be some bug where the exported constructor isn't set up right on Safari. The `jQuery` function they expose isn't the actual constructor, so I'm pretty sure they just give assign to `.prototype` the `.prototype` of the actual constructor. I wonder if replacement of the `.prototype` works, but the `instanceof` in Safari has a bug where it's not recognized.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's definitely odd but setting global variable to var LobbyMenuGames = $(); fixed it.

Comment: Yes, just be aware that there's almost definitely some code that is using that variable before the element exists. If whatever operation it needs to do is crucial, then it may cause other problems that will be revealed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is an `object` in Javascript, but your initial value is actually `undefined`. This behavior of treating `undefined` as matching `null` is likely browser-specific.

Try the simpler `!LobbyMenuGames` as either initial state (`null` or `undefined`) is *falsey*:

```
 var LobbyMenuGames;  // Global Variable
 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
      if (!LobbyMenuGames)
           LobbyMenuGames = $("#LobbyMenuGames");
 }
```

Or better yet ensure it is always a jQuery object using an *empty jQuery object*:

```
var LobbyMenuGames = $();  // Global Variable is an empty jQuery collection
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    LobbyMenuGames = $("#LobbyMenuGames");
}
```

This second method is handy for avoiding falsey checks on jQuery objects.

Comment: *"`null` is an `object` in Javascript,..."* That's not correct. It's always a *primitive*, though the `typeof` operator returns the string `"object"`. The `instanceof` operator isn't impacted by this. *"...This behavior of treating `undefined` as matching `null` is likely browser-specific..."* Not at all. The comparisons between `null` and `undefined` are not browser specific. It's well defined in ECMAScript.

Comment: Thanks, the first method didn't work but the second worked great.

Comment: @Atsso: Apparently my assumptions about null on the first part may be incorrect, but the second option is generally very useful in jQuery. I will investigate further as the original bug still makes no sense :)